# Getting an exception while trying to send a Email from website

Tags: html-email, smtpclient

It is working in my local code .It is not working in my published website:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 40.97.144.50:587
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

Kindly suggest some solutions

Comment: Your website doesn't have permission to access to the email server. It's probably blocked by a firewall

Comment: which firewall .is it my local or my website provider (hostgator